# How to add columns in Kendo UI Grid Dynamically using DataSource's Generic List?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid

This is the model I'm using:

```
public class DepartmentModel : TrackingModel
{
    #region Properties
    public long PKDepartmentID { get; set; }        

    [StringLength(255, ErrorMessage = "*")]
    public string Code { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "*")]
    public string Location { get; set; }

    [StringLength(400, ErrorMessage = "Max 400 characters")]
    public string Description { get; set; }


    public string Country_Code { get; set; }
    public string State_Code { get; set; }

    public string ServiceCentreName { get; set; }

    public List<FieldsModel> DepartmentExt { get; set; }

    #endregion
}

public class FieldsModel
{
    public string fieldName { get; set; }
    public string fieldValue { get; set; }
    public int dataType { get; set; }
}
```

---

How can I add columns from p.DepartmentExt (List Of FieldsModel Class)?

```
              @(Html.Kendo().Grid<Magellano.DAL.Models.DepartmentModel>()
                .Name("Grid")
                .Columns(columns =>
                {
                    if (Html.HasDeleteRights())
                    {
                        columns.Bound(p => p.PKDepartmentID).Title("<input id='chkDepartmentTop' type='checkbox' class='chkDepartmentTop'>").ClientTemplate("#= multipledeleteLink(data) #").Filterable(false).Sortable(false).Width(3);
                    }
                    columns.Bound(p => p.Code).Title("Code");
                    columns.Bound(p => p.Description).Title("Description");
                    columns.Bound(p => p.Location).Title("Location").Filterable(false);
                    columns.Bound(p => p.Country_Code).Title("Country").Filterable(false);
                    columns.Bound(p => p.State_Code).Title("State").Filterable(false);
                    columns.Bound(p => p.IsPrimary).Title("Primary");                        
                    columns.Bound("test");

                    // How To Add Columns from p.DepartmentExt (List Of FieldsModel Class)

                    // ajax binding
                    if (Html.HasEditRights())
                    {
                        columns.Bound(p => p.PKDepartmentID).ClientTemplate("#= projectDetails(data) #").Title("").Filterable(false).Width(3);
                    }
                    if (Html.HasDeleteRights())
                    {
                        columns.Bound(p => p.PKDepartmentID).ClientTemplate("#= projectDelete(data) #").Title("").Filterable(false).Width(3);
                    }

                })
                .Pageable(pageable => pageable
                            .PageSizes(new[] { 10, 20, 30 })
                        )

                .Sortable()
                .TableHtmlAttributes(new { dbleditable = "true", canEdit = Html.HasEditRights().ToString().ToLower(), canDelete = Html.HasDeleteRights().ToString().ToLower() })
                .Filterable()
                .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                .Ajax()
                .PageSize(10)
                .Model(model =>
                               {
                                   model.Field("test", typeof(string));
                               })

                .Read(read => read.Action("DepartmentList", "Department")))
            )
```

Comment: how did you do this? I have a very similar problem to solve.